# How do you validate Windows user credentials on a different machine over a WiFi or LAN network?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c

I am on machine "MACHINEA" in my WiFi or LAN network, and am trying to authenticate a user with username "testusername" and password "testpassword" on machine "MACHINEB" in my WiFi network. I don't have a domain controller on this network. I want to validate credentials on a regular machine, just because it is visible on the network. I would like a solution or suggestion in C#, but I am open to other suggestions in other languages if I can fork into a different process that can return a value to me in a different language (if possible, please explain how I could do this as well).

Comment: Windows, Linux or max on remote machine?  Simpe solutions would be to use a file share on remote machine with acces to any local user. Connecting using network credentails should cater for simple remote authentication.

Comment: Do you care if the password traverses the network in cleartext?

Comment: If you are on Wifi with a password, you have automatic encryption.  But not so on a LAN or open Wifi.

Comment: Its on a Windows machine. The problem is that file sharing may not be turned on, or if it is I suppose file sharing can become an issue because then you get into directory access rights. There must be another way, is there not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the equivalent in C# is but in C you can do this using the [`WNetAddConnection2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. Note that this requires that you don't already have a connection to the computer, and that the computer is configured for authentication (i.e. simple file sharing is turned off.) You don't need to specify a local name for the connection.

Comment: @Fantius Not unless you change a bunch of registry entries on the PCs to force them into Windows 95 compatibility.

Comment: Its on a Windows machine. The problem is that file sharing may not be turned on, or if it is I suppose file sharing can become an issue because then you get into directory access rights. There must be another way, is there not?

Comment: You can request to connect to \\COMPUTERNAME\IPC$ which all authenticated users have access to. (You might still need to enable sharing, even without having anything explicitly shared.)